# How much does the Enlarge/Reduce spell increase weapon damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, oversized-weapons

If we enlarge a character with the Enlarge/Reduce spell, he grows with the weapon
We have a rule for interacting with larger weapons on p.278 of the DMG. Which says that enlarged weapons have double damage dice.
So let's say we have a barbarian with an axe that does 1d12 damage. We cast Enlarge/Reduce on the barbarian and its damage becomes:

1. 2d12 + 1d4 because we use the big weapon rule from page 278 and get another 1d4 from the spell.
2. 1d12 + 1d4 because this rule does not apply to this spell.

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate as this question has been asked before. This is okay, duplicates can help point users to questions that have already been answered.